# Проблемы с меню

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

http://ketty.zzz.com.ua/

1. Проблема когда в десктоп версии наводишь на элемент меню, вылазит подменю и оно ниже чем основное. Игрался с `z-index` никак вообще не помогло.
2. В таблет версии, если много раз подряд нажать на кнопку menu, потом раскрыть под меню и в нем еще одно под меню, то высота основного подменю не растягивается.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие вопроса: в нём никакой ценности для посетителей сайта, так как не приведён образец кода. Приведена ссылка на сайт, как только мы ответим на вопрос топикстартер тут же поменяет код. И что будут смотреть следующие посетители, заинтересовавшиеся вопросом?

Comment: @AK я предлагаю не делать поспешных выводов. Скинул ссылку на сайт что бы удобнее смотреть было. Если что-то не понятно переспросите или не мешайтесь тут.

Comment: Тогда добавьте код в вопрос. Вот посмотрите например: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560461/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. классу `class="acc sub__menu"` поставь любой `background-color` и все заработает..

Comment: Спасибо помогло, только не этому классу, а mobile__mainli