# Спойлер для динамически добавляемых элементов js

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Имеется блок, в который динамически (ajax js) добавляются элементы с текстом. Текста может быть очень много. Необходимо часть текста скрывать, например после третьего элемента.

В проекте используется bootstrap v2.3.0, но решения, типо collapse не подходят. Как сделать ссылку спойлер [`...`](https://jsfiddle.net/98mf6b3L/1/) при нажатии на которую появится скрытый текст?

Разметка такая:

```
<span class="tags-list ">
    <a href="#">элемент1</a>
    <a href="#">элемент2</a>
    <a href="#">элемент3</a>
   <a href="#">...</a>
    а тут скрытый текст
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
 $(document).on('click','.toggler',toggleSpoiler);
 
  function toggleSpoiler(){
  var $parent = $(this).parent(),
   $spoiler = $parent.find('.spoiler'); 

   $spoiler.toggle();
 }

});
```

```css
.spoiler {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="tags-list ">
  <a href="#">элемент1</a>
    <a href="#">элемент2</a>
    <a href="#">элемент3</a>
    <a href="#" class="toggler">...</a>
    <span class="spoiler">
        а тут скрытый текст
    </span>
 </span>
```